# Unable to open a URL in external browser with Framework7 in Android device

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, html-framework-7

I am designing a Android Hybrid app with Framework7, the problem is I am not able to redirect to website in the external browser on button click. I have created an apk file using cordova and installed on device and checked.

JS Code:

```
//open url
$$('.external').on('click', function (e) {
var url = $$(this).attr("href");
window.open(url, "_blank");
```

HTML Code:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="link external button button-raised button-fill color-blue">Demo</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `_blank` to `_system` and it's will solve your problem.